# storing coords and various game data in arrays JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to JAVASCRIPT and this forum, well I've read many posts here but this is my first post.
I've taken to using arrays as shown below to store the majority of data for a game I'm building; this goes especially for game statistics and coordinates.
The example below is one of my smaller arrays. I keep them all in an excel spreadsheet which is particularly handy when I need to adjust some data as they are all concatenated automatically. So then I just copy the chunk of code and paste it in my javascript. This example mainly stores coordinates for the inventory slots and what kind of items they each hold.

```
//ENEMY INV ARAY COORDS
function enemyinvcoords(name, x1, y1, x2, y2, item, state){
this.name = name, this.x1 = x1, this.x2 = x2, this.y1 = y1, this.y2 = y2, this.item = item, this.state = state;
}
//CREATE AND FILL INVCOORDSARRAY
var ENinvarr = [];
ENinvarr.push(new enemyinvcoords('EI0', 420, 280, 460, 320, 1, false));
ENinvarr.push(new enemyinvcoords('EI1', 465, 280, 505, 320, 2, false));
ENinvarr.push(new enemyinvcoords('EI2', 510, 280, 550, 320, 3, false));
ENinvarr.push(new enemyinvcoords('EI3', 555, 280, 595, 320, 4, false));
ENinvarr.push(new enemyinvcoords('EI4', 600, 280, 640, 320, 5, false));
ENinvarr.push(new enemyinvcoords('EI5', 645, 280, 685, 320, 6, false));
ENinvarr.push(new enemyinvcoords('EI6', 690, 280, 730, 320, 7, false));
```

Is there anything wrong with this method? so far it's been very handy when populating the screen and editing statistics as it allows me to keep my code short by using for loops that run through the required arrays. Do you have any advice of how I might be able to store these things in a better way? I am in the long run planning to have this game communicate with a server of some kind but for the moment I'm just designing game mechanics and UI interaction. I suspect there will be many rewrites before that ever happens though. I'm probably asking this a bit late though, if this turns out to be a bad way to work then I feel another rewrite coming up. 
Any advice you have would be most welcome. 
Many Thanks and kind regards,

Comment: It's a bit broad. Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: You mean I'd be better of asking this question there instead?

Comment: Yeah, that site is for code review and the folks there are pretty eager to help and make suggestions. The question above isn't really an answerable question, more of a quest for opinions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO this could be done a bit simpler, I would maybe create it like that:

```
function enemyinvcoords(name, x1, y1, x2, y2, item, state){
   return { name : name, x1 : x1, x2 : x2, y1 : y1, y2 : y2, item : item, state : state}; 
}

var ENinvarr = [
    enemyinvcoords('EI0', 420, 280, 460, 320, 1, false),
    enemyinvcoords('EI1', 465, 280, 505, 320, 2, false),
    enemyinvcoords('EI2', 510, 280, 550, 320, 3, false),
    enemyinvcoords('EI3', 555, 280, 595, 320, 4, false),
    enemyinvcoords('EI4', 600, 280, 640, 320, 5, false),
    enemyinvcoords('EI5', 645, 280, 685, 320, 6, false),
    enemyinvcoords('EI6', 690, 280, 730, 320, 7, false)
];
```

Hope that helps you a little to jump into JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks! That is shorter/simpler I will use it. I guess it is a bit of a general question. **I really just wanted to know whether using arrays in this way might create problems for my game later on**. But I appreciate the advise nonetheless.